# iframe src from angularjs is not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, angularjs, iframe

I am trying to retrieve youtube link from mysql using php and embed it in a webpage with angularjs. The issue is that all other data is displayed on the webpage except the iframe. As you can see in the View on my code below, that the I have displayed the post.src on the webpage. The link is exactly what I expected. However, when I try to embed it and try to pass the link using {{ post.src }} in iframe source, it does not show anything, but it makes some space as it was instructed from iframe width and height.

Any thoughts???

```
<!-- HTML content -->
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="videoControl">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <td>{{ post.postType }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.postTitle }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.postDescription }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.postDate }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.src }} </td>
        <td>
            <iframe width='560' height='315' ng-src='{{ post.src }}' frameborder='0' allow='autoplay; encrypted-media' allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>







<!-- module -->
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);






<!-- controller -->
app.controller('videoControl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("pages/db_section/videos.php")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.posts = response.data.records;
    });
});






<!-- videos.php -->
<?php

include 'db.php';

connection();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM feed WHERE post_type='video' ORDER BY time DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}

    $source = str_replace("watch?v=","embed/",$rs["src"]);

    $outp .= '{"postType":"'  . $rs["post_type"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"postDate":"'   . $rs["time"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"postTitle":"'   . $rs["post_title"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"src":"'   . $source      . '",';
    $outp .= '"postDescription":"'. $rs["post_description"]     . '"}';
}
$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';


connectionClose();

echo($outp);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a filter, where 'post.src' is the URL of the iframe and 'trustAsResourceUrl' is the filter and is defined

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.filter('trustAsResourceUrl', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
    };
}])
```

and HTML

```
 <iframe width='560' height='315' ng-src='{{ post.src | trustAsResourceUrl}}' frameborder='0' allow='autoplay; encrypted-media' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```